# When I load New Scene With SteamVR_LoadLevel All Controllers Freezing

Tags: unity-game-engine, steamvr

Hey i am working on VR application with unity. I have got some scenes in my project. Everythings are fine first scenes. There is a level i am using a "Player" prefab and when i start a load new scene with SteamVR_LoadLevel .Begin function, next scene loading finely and my HMD running good but the controllers freeze. I am CameraRig in next scene and i destroy Player [SteamVR] gameobject before scene with checkbox (unchecked) inside of inspector.

I was try Unity SceneManagement, or other things but i can not find a solution. By the way if i run that scene directly, every controller working fine.

Waiting your answers thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can not find solution on this problem but i change my GameObjects. I think if you use Player prefab previous scene and if you use CameraRig inside next scene then controllers freezing. Because vr action setup not same (or broken) for CameraRig. When i realized this situation, i change my CameraRig object to Player prefab. If you accept, this is my solution.